# Haskell dependency hell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to include a specific version of a library in a Haskell project. The library is bed-and-breakfast (which is used for martix operations), but I need the specific version 0.4.3 which fixed a bug with the multiplication implementation.

So, my stack.yaml looks like this:

```
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages:
- .
extra-deps:
- bed-and-breakfast-0.4
- base-4.6.0.1
resolver: lts-12.8
```

But I'm getting this error when building:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for bed-and-breakfast-0.4:
    base-4.11.1.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.5 && <4.7  (latest matching version
                  is 4.6.0.1)
needed due to realworldhaskell-0.1.0.0 -> bed-and-breakfast-0.4

Some different approaches to resolving this:


  * Set 'allow-newer: true' to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

  * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to attempt to find some
    working build configuration. This can be convenient when dealing with many complicated
    constraint errors, but results may be unpredictable.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps
    in C:\Users\info\Desktop\Projects\haskell\stack.yaml:

- base-4.6.0.1
```

I've done the recommended action but it didn't solve anything. I've tried using different resolvers to see if it's an issue with my GHCi version but nothings worked. What is the best way to interpret error messages like this and how should I proceed?

EDIT:

If I remove -base.4.6.0.1 and add allow-newer: true I get this:

```
WARNING: Ignoring out of range dependency (allow-newer enabled): base-4.11.1.0. bed-and-breakfast requires: >=4.5 && <4.7
bed-and-breakfast-0.4: configure
Progress 1/2

--  While building custom Setup.hs for package bed-and-breakfast-0.4 using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.3.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\7d103d30 configure --with-ghc=C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.4.3\bin\ghc.EXE --with-g
hc-pkg=C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.4.3\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=C:\sr\snapshots\76fd1958\pkgdb --package-db=C:\Users\info\Desktop\Projects\haskell\
.stack-work\install\8c390635\pkgdb --libdir=C:\Users\info\Desktop\Projects\haskell\.stack-work\install\8c390635\lib --bindir=C:\Users\info\Desktop\Projects\haskell\.stack-work\install\8c390635\bin --datadir=C:\Users\info\Desktop\Proj
ects\haskell\.stack-work\install\8c390635\share --libexecdir=C:\Users\info\Desktop\Projects\haskell\.stack-work\install\8c390635\libexec --sysconfdir=C:\Users\info\Desktop\Projects\haskell\.stack-work\install\8c390635\etc --docdir=C:
\Users\info\Desktop\Projects\haskell\.stack-work\install\8c390635\doc\bed-and-breakfast-0.4 --htmldir=C:\Users\info\Desktop\Projects\haskell\.stack-work\install\8c390635\doc\bed-and-breakfast-0.4 --haddockdir=C:\Users\info\Desktop\Pr
ojects\haskell\.stack-work\install\8c390635\doc\bed-and-breakfast-0.4 --dependency=array=array-0.5.2.0 --dependency=base=base-4.11.1.0 --dependency=binary=binary-0.8.5.1 --dependency=deepseq=deepseq-1.4.3.0 --dependency=template-hask
ell=template-haskell-2.13.0.0 --extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\min

gw64\bin --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib --exact-configuration
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: C:\Users\info\Desktop\Projects\haskell\.stack-work\logs\bed-and-breakfast-0.4.log

    Configuring bed-and-breakfast-0.4...
    Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.3.exe: The package has an impossible
    version range for a dependency on an internal library: bed-and-breakfast
    ==0.3.2. This version range does not include the current package, and must be
    removed as the current package's library will always be used.
```

EDIT 2:

Ok, so I'm guessing that the bed-and-breakfast library needs base 4.11.1.0 which is included in GHCi 6.10.2 (according to https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package) so I need a resolver which matches that GHCi version. Where can I find out what resolver version that is?

Comment: You can't change `base` version, it's wired in with ghc, so try removing `- base-4.6.0.1` from extra-deps and setting `allow-newer: true`.

Comment: I think you will need to use another *snapshot* (the resoler `lts-12.8` probably is not compatible).

Comment: Yea, I've tried setting my resolver to earlier versions, but it's like a guessing game. Is there some logical way I can find out what resolver I need?

Comment: Hi! I'm the author of `bed-and-breakfast` and I just released 0.5 which should fix these issues.

Comment: Nice one Scravy - I'll check it out this weekend!

Comment: Does the update support non square matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the constraint on the latest available `bed-and-breakfast` package: `base (>=4.5 && <4.7)`, which means it will likely not even compile with GHC version higher then 7.6. Considering that there is even no LTS snapshot prior to GHC 7.8, you are out of luck with that package.

To say it in another words, the package is outdated and your choices are:

- submit an issue and hope maintainer will do something about it
- try to make it work with newer ghc yourself
- Use a different package

Comment: Right, this is actually one of the possible conclusions I had come to. I hear HMatrix is a good alternative, but when I include that as a dependency the build fails telling me I'm missing OpenBLAS (which after some digging looks like I need to install mingw and setup a load of C dependencies... is there any easier way of setting up all this without going into building C libs etc?

Comment: Yeah, switch to Linux ;) Just kidding. `HMatrix` is a wrapper around OpenBLAS so there is no way around it if you want to use that package. Depending on what operations you need there are other array manipulation libraries that might  work for you. I am an author of `massiv` package, but it doesn't have many algebraic operations included yet, but it is pure Haskell, so external dependencies needed.

Comment: Well I actually started switching to linux for precisely this reason; windows is a very annoying environment to work in... but, vidya games xD

I will take a look at your massiv package (lol...), is it open source (i.e. if I roll my own matrix operations using pure haskell you might consider merging them in via PR if they match you're packages theme?)

Comment: Yes, it is open source. You can find it on hackage and here github.com/lehins/massiv I'll be happy to accept a PR, but before doing the work it might be worth opening an issue for the things you might want to add.

Comment: @AlexeyKuleshevich note that “matrix operations” in the conventional sense (Matlab / NumPy / bed-and-breakfast / HMatrix / etc.) go rather against the grain of Haskell itself, what with their unsafe runtime dimensions. The idiomatic thing to do in Haskell is to distinguish vector spaces through the type system. You may want to check out [linear](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear), which is 100% native and takes a very Haskell-specific approach. (Which I find not optimal either, mind, prompting me to write [free-vector-spaces](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-vector-spaces).)

Comment: @ThomasCook Note that even on windows you can often use pacman (`stack exec pacman`) to get necessary dependencies. Not sure if OpenBLAS is available through that, but its worth a try.